# Currency and Percent fields in one formula

Tags: community, formula-field

I need a build a one field which display value of percent or amount so we have object A and he has 3 fields:

percent: 20%

amount:100 EUR

ABC – our formula (Currenty her type is number)

How it should work? 
When the percent is 0 then display amount with currency in ABC formula.

When the amount is 0 then display percents in ABC formula.

I’ve build the formula but I don’t know how can I join these fields into one formula ? Have You got any idea how may I do this ?

Type of formula is Number at the moment.

```
IF(Percent__c = 0,Amount__c,
IF(Amount__c = 0,Percent__c * 100,null))”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use a TEXT field, and return the types as text:

```
IF(Percent__c=0, TEXT(Amount__c)&' '&TEXT(CurrencyISOCode), TEXT(Percent__c*100)&'%')
```

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, 

I've used your formula but the issue is "Field CurrencyIsoCode is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions"
You know how to get appriopriate value of this field ?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it - thanks sfdcfox

Comment: @Freeezer789 Yeah, you're right. I'll fix that too in my answer for future visitors.